# Pre fill a input field from incoming link

Tags: php, forms

We have a Quenstion and Answer script we have made.

Essentially, the form element looks like this ( I think the issue I have is POST and not GET )

Anyway will ask anyway.

On the Q and A page, users can enter title and question. So form looks a tad like this:

```
<form method="post">
  <input id="askit" type="text" name="q_desc" value="">
    ...blah blah blah
</form>
```

Basically, I want to add a input field on an external page ( same domain ) so that when user clicks submit, it takes them to the Q and A page, and propagates the input field in the form above with the value of what they typed on previous page.

For this purpose I have added the id="askit"

So basically, the external page would fire something like this:

www.somewebsite.com/questions/?askit=hello+world

Because my form uses Post, I am pretty sure this is where it is going pear shaped.

Any suggestions please. ? The form must be POST because it is for submitting questions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To get `http://www.somewebsite.com/questions/?askit=hello+world` to working you need to update your code above in the following way:

```
<?php
    $askit = '';
    if(array_key_exists('askit', $_GET)) {
        $askit = $_GET['askit'];
    }
?>
<form method="post">
  <input id="askit" type="text" name="q_desc" 
         value="<?php echo htmlentities($askit); ?>">
    ...blah blah blah
</form>
```

Comment: Thanks, is this safe ? Not that I am questioning its safety, just asking. Will give it a whirl, thankyou.

Comment: It is reasonably safe in that any HTML entered will be escaped. There is probably additional sanitisation that you may like to do though such as `filter_var()` with `FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING`.

Comment: Thanks :) will give it a whirl.

Answer (score 2):

You can still mix and match POST and GET data on this form using the `$_POST` and `$_GET` PHP super globals, respectively.

```
<form method="post">
  <imput id="askit" type="text" name="q_desc" value="<?php echo isset($_GET['askit']) ? htmlspecialchars($_GET['askit']) : ''; ?>">
</form>
```

Although I am not recommending it, you're life might be easier by using `$_REQUEST` which is a merge of both POST and GET data.

Comment: I am not 100% sure on _request method, could you please elaborate

Answer (score 1):

its really easy, all you need to do it get the value submitted by the user using `$_GET['']` or `$_POST['']` depending on the request, and then echo it as a value of the input, so something like :

`<input id="askit" type="text" name="q_desc" value="<?php echo $_GET['askit']?>">`

you can always use htmlentities() to make sure that the form is safe and prevent people messing with your html.